# Matlab to python conversion mslice[]

Tags: python, matlab

The following is used in a Matlab code.

```
Cf=zeros(17,17);
Cf=C; Cf(1:16,17)=C(1:16,16); Cf(17,1:16)=C(16,1:16); Cf(17,17)=C(16,16);
```

I would like to translate the above code to python coding language. So I used OMPC from the following link: http://ompclib.appspot.com/m2py and it outputs the following result:

```
Cf = zeros(17, 17)
Cf = C
Cf(mslice[1:16], 17).lvalue = C(mslice[1:16], 16); print Cf
Cf(17, mslice[1:16]).lvalue = C(16, mslice[1:16])
Cf(17, 17).lvalue = C(16, 16)
```

My problem is that I am not familiar with mslice[] or its use. I have never seen this used in python and python gives me an invalid syntax error. I know OMPC is a bit outdated, so does anyone have any tips on how I would translate the portion of the Matlab code I pasted above into python langauge? (I have never worked with Matlab so I am not familiar with the coding language, any tips are much appreciated)

Comment: What is `C`? And why are you copying first C to the whole Cf and then only portions of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing arrays in python is done with square brackets i.e. `Cf[i,j]` and to iterate you can do it the same way as in matlab, however starts counting from 0 instead as 1, e.g. `C[0:10,5]`. And you also need to import the zeros function from numpy.

I guess what you want to do becomes then

```py
import numpy as np
Cf = np.zeros([17,17])
Cf = C
Cf[0:15,16]=C[0:15,15]
Cf[16,0:15]=C[15,0:15] 
Cf[16,16]=C[15,15]
```